# JApplet size in Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, applet, size, japplet

I'm currently developping a little game for learning purpose, it currently work as a JApplet and so far I've had no issue with it, but I'm getting different size in Firefox and Chrome, see :

In Google Chrome(And IE) it's working fine :

[image]

But in Firefox I'm getting this :

[image]

My HTML code looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML>
    <BODY>
<p>
<object type="application/x-java-applet"
    name="previewersGraph" width="800" height="600">
    <param name="codebase" value="." />
    <param name="code" value="choups.game.Fenetre" />
    <param name="archive" value="choup.jar" />
    <param name="scriptable" value="true" />
    <param name="mayscript" value="true" />
    <param name="file" value="/report_files/1-1272041330710YAIwK" />
</object>
</p>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

My JApplet contructor contain this :

```
    setSize(800, 600);
    setVisible(true);
```

Does anyone have any ideas ?

Thanks :]

Comment: *"Does anyone have any ideas ?"*  Yes. 1) Remove the only two code lines shown.  The first is something that should be done in the HTML.  The second is true by default (for any component added to a displayed container - which happens automatically for applets). 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) But.. Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: Your first solution hasn't changed anything I'm afraid. It seems that Firefox "zoom" the applet or something, I'm not sure how to fix that in CSS.

Comment: @Inpu: “Your first solution hasn't changed anything I'm afraid.” That’s obvious. He was telling you that these two lines have no effect. So removing them does not change anything but making your code cleaner.